# Titan 0.5.1 AttributeSerializer cannot be resolved

Tags: titan

I have a little problem with Titan 0.5.1. I try to upgrade my source code from 0.4.4 to 0.5.1. I have different problem and i dont find in the new documentation.

In my project i have custom class. When i use Titan 0.4.4 i write this for KryoSerializer :

```
    import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInput;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutput;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.commons.lang.ArrayUtils;

import com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.AttributeSerializer;
import com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.ScanBuffer;
import com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.WriteBuffer;

public class CharacteristicSerializer implements AttributeSerializer<Characteristic> {


    public Characteristic read(ScanBuffer buffer) {
        Characteristic object = null;
        ArrayList<Byte> records = new ArrayList<Byte>();

        try {
            while (buffer.hasRemaining()) {
                records.add(Byte.valueOf(buffer.getByte()));
            }

            Byte[] bytes = records.toArray(new Byte[records.size()]);

            ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(ArrayUtils.toPrimitive(bytes));
            ObjectInput in = new ObjectInputStream(bis);
            object = (Characteristic) in.readObject();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return object;
    }

    public void writeObjectData(WriteBuffer out, Characteristic charac) {
        try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ObjectOutput outobj;

            outobj = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);

            outobj.writeObject(charac);
            byte[] propertybyte = bos.toByteArray();

            for (int i = 0; i < propertybyte.length; i++) {
                out.putByte(propertybyte[i]);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Characteristic convert(Object arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public void verifyAttribute(Characteristic arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


}
```

So when i use Titan 0.5.1 i have this error :
AttributeSerializer cannot be resolved to a type.

My question is : How can i upgrade my source code ?

in advance thanks all

Answer (score 0):

`AttributeSerializer` moved to the `attribute` subpackage in Titan 0.5.0.  Change

`import com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.AttributeSerializer;`

to

`import com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.attribute.AttributeSerializer;`

There may be other migration issues porting the 0.4.x app to 0.5.x.  I only looked at the AttributeSerializer type resolution error you pasted.

Comment: Thanks Dan for this information, and thanks auto-completion ;)